# CoreData IOS: How to create an object with values without it being marked as having changes

Tags: ios, core-data, initialization, nsmanagedobject

I've no idea how complicated this can be,

I have an app that uses CoreData.

When I create a new managed object, I populate its fields with default values sotred in a plist.

Then I display a bunch of forms (loading the saved values into the forms and updating the values of the object as I go along).

And at the end I check if the object hasChanges and suggest to save the object.

This part works fine.

However when I'm having trouble when the user hits "Back" in the interface. I want to be able to display an Alert if the user has changed anything in the object or let the user go back if nothing has been changed.

I would you hasChanges, however, since I populate the object with default data, CoreData conceders that the object has been changed to start with.

So how can I create a new managed object and initialise it without ti being considered as changes

```
- (Company *)createNewDefaultCompany:(NSString *)name{
    Company *company = [Company insertInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [company setName:name];
    [company setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [company setLocalisation:@"en_UK"];

    Input *input = [Input insertInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [input populateWithDefault];
    [company setCompanyInputs:input];

    Formulas *formulas = [Formulas insertInManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
    [formulas populateWithDefault];
    [company setCompanyFormula:formulas];

    [company createCalculus];
    return company;
}
```

The creation of the managed object.

```
+(Company *)insertInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    return (Company *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really test this out, but what you might consider doing is saving the managed object context after your `company` Managed Object is set up, and then checking for changes after this save. To get rid of your new object if the user backs out, you can just call the `deleteObject` method in your managed context, passing it the reference to your new object. Just make sure you save the context again after deleting the object.

Answer (score 0):

Once possible way to do this would be to use an NSUndoManager on your managed object context. You could wrap your default value setting in a block of code where undo registration was disabled:

```
- (Company *)createNewDefaultCompany:(NSString *)name{
    [[managedObjectContext undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];

    Company *company = [Company insertInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [company setName:name];
    [company setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [company setLocalisation:@"en_UK"];

    Input *input = [Input insertInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [input populateWithDefault];
    [company setCompanyInputs:input];

    Formulas *formulas = [Formulas insertInManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
    [formulas populateWithDefault];
    [company setCompanyFormula:formulas];

    [company createCalculus];

    [managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
    [[managedObjectContext undoManager] enableUndoRegistration];

    return company;
}
```

and then check the `canUndo` state on the undo manager. Assuming there were no undoable actions coming into this view controller (you could clear this with `-removeAllActions` on your undo manager when entering or exiting the view controller), the undo state should reflect whether any changes were made after you created and initialized this NSManagedObject.

This might not be the best solution, however, if you want to use undo elsewhere with your managed object context, given the need to wipe the undo state before creating the company object.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the NSManagedObject is not marked as changed, you should not use the normal setters, but use setPrimitiveValue: instead.
BTW: Normally, NSManagedObject initialization is done in the awakeFromInsert method.